# Herança de Formulário criado em Runtime

Tags: delphi, herança, polimorfismo, delphi-10

Segue o código abaixo:

```
type
  TfObject = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure FormShow(Sender : TObject);
    procedure FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

Código do Create:

```
constructor TfObject.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  Position := TPosition.poScreenCenter;
  WindowState := wsNormal;
  KeyPreview := true;
  AlphaBlend := true;
  AlphaBlendValue := 0;
  BorderStyle := bsSizeable;

  OnShow := FormShow;
  OnKeyDown := FormKeyDown;
  OnClose := FormClose;
end;
```

O problema é o seguinte, de acordo com o que eu sei relacionado a Delphi com O.O., eu poderia utilizar desta forma para conseguir herdar os métodos contidos na classe Pai, porém, quando faço dessa forma, eu não consigo utilizar o `inherited` na classe filha, que é no caso o formulário que está herdando de `TfObject`.

Descobri que fazendo a classe desta forma, eu consigo utilizar normalmente os métodos do formulário, mas quando eu ponho para os métodos do formulário (`OnShow`, `OnClose`, `OnKeyDown`) para receber os seus devidos métodos, ele se comporta como se a classe filha estivesse fazendo isso.

Agora minha pergunta...

Como faço para minha classe `TForm` atribuir seus métodos do formulário e eu apenas herdá-los quando eu implemento um método (`OnShow`, `OnClose`, `OnKeyDown`)?

Exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(sender : TObject);
begin
  //faz algo
  inherited;
  //faz algo
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você esta atribuindo um evento e não método diretamente. Sugiro olhar a classe TCustomForm que é a classe pai da TForm, la estão os métodos que podem ser sobrescritos. Sendo assim, use os métodos DoShow, DoClose, etc.. Estes chamam os eventos, mas podem ser substituídos. Veja o exemplo:

```
type
  TForm7 = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure MetodoSubstituivel; virtual;
    procedure DoShow; override;
  public

  end;

implementation

procedure TForm7.DoShow;
begin
  showmessage('antes');
  inherited;
  showmessage('depois');
end;

procedure TForm7.MetodoSubstituivel;
begin
  //algo aqui
end;
```

Comment: Bom, implementei anteriormente desta forma, mas cada vez que declaro o Formulário Filho herdando do Pai, eu consigo utilizar o `DoShow` Normalmente, mas o `FormShow` do formulário filho não existe o `inheirted`, devido a quando se cria o mesmo, ele atribui ao método que está rodando agora.

Comment: Exato, acontece que o FormShow é um método declarado na classe local (filha), ela não esta substituindo a do pai. 
procedure FormShow(Sender : TObject);
Não tem virtual e nem override. Isto porque é o método disparado pelo evento atribuído apenas localmente, neste caso não tem como usar inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Para usar inherited em um método da classe filha, chamando o método da classe pai, ele deve ser declarado como a diretiva virtual na classe pai e override na classe filha.

Comment: Eu sei, o problema é que o método virtual já está declarado, mas quando se cria um formulário pela aplicação, seus eventos já foram criados com sucesso, e dá para herdar tranquilamente, eu quero fazer o mesmo, só que declarando apenas uma classe, e não precisar criar o formulário pela aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Ramon, confesso que não entendi bem sua necessidade. Você quer que o evento da classe filha não aconteça a não ser que chamado explicitamente?